# How can I get the Document Libraries permissions in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm developing a Webpart and I need to go through every document library and get its permissions. Basically I need to get the groups and its permissions associated with the document library.

I have iterated through the properties and methods of a `SPDocumentLibrary` object but couldn't find anything really.

Any help or guide would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check [HasUniqueRoleAssignments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurableobject.hasuniqueroleassignments.aspx). If it is false, then the permissions for that document library are inherited from the website. If it is true, as Jason said, I would then check the [Member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.member.aspx) and [RoleDefinitionBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.roledefinitionbindings.aspx) of each [SPRoleAssignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproleassignment.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try SPDocomentLibrary.RoleAssignments.
This will give you SPRoleAssignments where the Member property is a SPGroup or a SPUser.